# Filter a dataframe based on string column

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have read a text file in jupyter notebook and want to fetch some sentences containing particular words. My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = open(r"new2.txt", "rt") 
contents = df.read()
print(contents)
df[df['text'].str.contains('possession|chemical report|S.|chemical examination|act|witness|appeal|dismissed|refused|judgement')]
```

Comment: What is the issue with the above code; could you add more details please.

Comment: It seems that your code should work. What output do you get ?

Comment: the whole text file is imported that's OK, but when im running the last command its not filtering those particular sentences from imported text file, the specific words are also mentioned.  it showing error KeyError: 'text'

Comment: im working on court trials raw data, and i want to make a summary while selecting some meaningful sentences from the document. so instead of thorough study of whole document i just want to extract some sentences while passing some keywords.  Plz guide if anyone knows...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanx for your kind concern :), Problem is solved.